# Visible point light

Tags: graphics3d, lighting

Is there a way to create a visible light sphere for point light?

The default behavior is the following:
[image: cube with point light]

And the desired is the following:
[image: cube with visible point light]

---

I'm working in [mathics-threejs-backend](https://github.com/Mathics3/mathics-threejs-backend), the 3d graphics backend for [Mathics](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics), and we want to know if there is a way of adding a visible light sphere to the scene without an additional sphere primitive.

Comment: I don’t think there is a way to do what you want without at the very least generating a primitive to act as the source for your light, but I am curious to see what response you get to this!